# Validation. Checking and calling a function

Tags: javascript

I want to call a function only when the form is valid. Validation works correctly, but I can not correctly call the addUser () function. The test worked, but it's looped, the next time it's called, the test is done twice, the next 5 times. There can be several telephones.

---

```
        // code

      if (lastName.value.match(letters)) {    
        for(var i = 0; i < phones.length; i++){
          if (!phones[i].value.match(digts)) {
          //checking
            if(phones[phones.length - 1].value != '') {
              addUser();
            };
            error.innerHTML = 'Only digits';
            frm.insertBefore(error, phones[i]);
            break;
          }
        }
          } else {
        if(user.value == ''){
            //code
        }
           errorMessage = "false";
        }
          if (errorMessage !== "") {
              event.preventDefault();
          }
        }

----------

function addUser(){
    $('#registration').submit(function(event) {
      alert(12);
       //code
      event.preventDefault();
      var data = 'phones=' + JSON.stringify(arrUserInfo);
      $.ajax({
        //code
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Explain `I can not correctly call the addUser () function`, because `addUser()` *is* correct function all. Also check if all your `{` matches `}`. Because looks like after `addUser()` there is `};` in if...

Comment: Inside your submit callback, since you are using an ajax call. You should call `event.preventDefault()` for it to cancel posting.

Comment: why not use [jquery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) then you can just use something like [`if ($form.valid()) {}`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/).  But I think your problem is your add user only binds a submit event - each time you submit your form and it is valid, you bind it again, try using off to clear any previous bindings - or just bind the event on document ready - the form should only be submitted if it is valid so you only need to bind it once

Comment: I changed and added code. @ngeksyo

Comment: I changed and added code @Pete

Comment: Yes I saw, my previous comment addresses that

Answer (score 0):

You can add validations in another function and return true or false depending on validation result,and call that function on form submit.

```
function validations()
{
   ....

   for(var i = 0; i < phones.length; i++){
     if (!phones[i].value.match(digts)) {
    // set error message
    return false;
    }
   }    

  if(user.value == ''){
      // set error message
     return false;
   }
   return true;
}

$('#registration').submit(function(event) { 
     if(validations())
     {
            $.ajax({
            // code
            });
     }
     else
      {
          return false;
       }
    });
```

Comment: I do not quite understand what you want @arjun

Comment: you may group validation check in another function and then call that function in submit callback,rather than binding submit event after validation check.i think you are checking validations on button click right?